# android define function across activity fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**warning:** I'm a newbie;

originally I use a baseActivity contain all my functions. but lately I use some fragment instead, but how can I achive something like baseActivity?

**code example:**

```
public class baseActivity extends Activity{
.....
    public void showMyWarning(String s){
       ....
    }
}

public class myActivity extends baseActivity{
    .....
    showMyWarning("WARNING!!");
}
```

but in fragment, how can I do this: in one class contain all my functions. all functions can be used across activity and fragment?

**thanks so much.**

Comment: What about create static function? Like: `YourUtils.showYourWarning(Context,String)`

Comment: if there is a better way? maybe ? less code modification.

Comment: make a static instance variable of your myActivity in myActivity class itself and to initialise it onCreate();

myActivity myActivityInstance=this;

then in your fragment,call your method using that static instance. Since you are using fragment, so fragment is attached to parent myActivity class already.
myActivity.myActivityInstance.showMyWarning();

Comment: thanks a lot ! @Harish Vats

Comment: if it helped.. u can upvote my comment :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1:**  Use `BaseFragment`

I think you need to create `BaseFragment` as same like `baseAcivity`.
Example code to create `BaseFragment` is below.

**Code:**

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment{
.....
public void showMyWarning(String s){
   ....
}
}

public class YourFragment extends BaseFragment{
 .....
  showMyWarning("WARNING!!");
}
```

**Case 2:** Access public method of class

If method from `baseActivity` which you want to access in any fragment need to do like below.

**Code:**

```
new baseAcivity().showMyWarning("WARNING!!");
```

**Case 3:** Access static method of class

For static method use, you need make `showMyWarning("")` as `static`.

**Code:**

```
public class baseActivity extends Activity{
  .....
  public static void showMyWarning(String s){
   ....
 }
}
```

Use static method.

**Code**

```
baseActivity.showMyWarning("WARNING!!");
```

Hope its helps you :)